# Create a JSON Literal in java without need for existing class

Tags: java, json, scala

In scala there's an API to create json string without the need to have existing class to be encoded into json, for example:

```
val json: JsValue = Json.obj(
    "name" -> "Watership Down",
    "location" -> Json.obj("lat" -> 51.235685, "long" -> -1.309197),
    "residents" -> Json.arr(
      Json.obj(
        "name" -> "Fiver",
        "age" -> 4,
        "role" -> JsNull
      ),
      Json.obj(
        "name" -> "Bigwig",
        "age" -> 6,
        "role" -> "Owsla"
      )
    )
  )
```

I know it is verbose, but sometimes it is handy.

Do Java has similar library, or I should have a class to be converted to Json String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not wrong you were asking for a JSON object builder. [This](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) will help you I guess.

```
  import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

  JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
  obj.put("name","foo");
  obj.put("num",new Integer(100));
  obj.put("balance",new Double(1000.21));
  obj.put("is_vip",new Boolean(true));
  obj.put("nickname",null);
  System.out.print(obj);
```

So basically you have to include the latest .jar file in your class path and you are good to go.

[This](https://jsonp.java.net/) would also help. this is distributed mainly via maven.

Comment: I assume it could be used from maven. Thanks

Comment: I've edited my answer for another project. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks alot, I see the one from javax is good, however I had to use the same feature from fasterxml.Jackson (JsonNodeFactory) as we already use jackson in the project.

Comment: still too verbose... isn't any library that accepts python style dictionary literals?